# Call a coroutine using RxJava without a scope

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to know how I can call a coroutine using RxJava and without using any scope.

If I have

```
suspend fun fetchInfo()  {
    //some code here
}
```

- Does it have to return an Observable ??
- Caller should be able to specify the running thread (i.e Schedulers.IO )
- I might be able to use runBlocking but not sure how to connect everything.

Thanks

Comment: You can only call a suspend function from another suspend function or from a Coroutine builder like launch. I am not using RxJava myself but I can imagine that there are adapters to connect Coroutines with RxJava.

Comment: There exist [bridges](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2#module-kotlinx-coroutines-rx2) between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rxSingle`, `rxObservable` function

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.rx3.rxObservable
import kotlinx.coroutines.rx3.rxSingle

rxSingle { fetchInfo() }
rxObservable { send(fetchInfo()) }
```

https://github.com/hoc081098/ComicReaderApp_MVI_Coroutine_RxKotlin_Jetpack/blob/f4e89036b934f8233d6d6ded941b19b702467405/app/src/main/java/com/hoc/comicapp/data/repository/ComicRepository1Impl.kt#L27

https://github.com/hoc081098/ComicReaderApp_MVI_Coroutine_RxKotlin_Jetpack/blob/f4e89036b934f8233d6d6ded941b19b702467405/app/src/main/java/com/hoc/comicapp/ui/search_comic/SearchComicInteractorImpl.kt#L20